# why url is appending just after contextpath in ajax success Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to open `google` page in my local host just inside ajax success handler .Here is how I am trying so far.

```
$(".write-portal").off("click").on("click",function (event) {   
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var pageId = $(this).attr('data-pageBodyId');
var windowUrl= window.location.href;        
var postData={"windowUrl":windowUrl};
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : contextpath + "/perform-logout",
    data : postData,
    async:false,
    success : function(msg) {
         window.open("www.google.com","google",'width=700,height=600,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')
        //window.location.href = "www.google.com";
        /*if(msg){
            window.location.assign(customUrl);
        }*/
    },
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

    }
});
});
```

It opens out a pop up but url is having `contextpath + www.google.com`.However I want simply www.google.com

Comment: Looks like it's doing a relative path, just add http:// in front of the domain name maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an absolute URL when opening the window. Try this:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", ...
```